# Create mocks with auto-filled properties with Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have an object (like the HttpContext or other ones) that I would like to mock. Sometimes, there are some unit tests where I'm forced to mock a hefty amount of dependencies, and set their dependencies and values appropriately.

Below there's some sample code to mock the httpcontext and another class:

```
    public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
    {
        var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var files = new Mock<HttpFileCollectionBase>();
        var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var session = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();
        var server = new Mock<HttpServerUtilityBase>();
        var user = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        var identity = new Mock<IIdentity>();
        request.Setup(req => req.ApplicationPath).Returns("~/");
        request.Setup(req => req.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns("~/");
        request.Setup(req => req.PathInfo).Returns(string.Empty);
        request.Setup(req => req.Form).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        request.Setup(req => req.QueryString).Returns(new NameValueCollection());
        request.Setup(req => req.Files).Returns(files.Object);
        response.Setup(res => res.ApplyAppPathModifier(MoqIt.IsAny<string>())).
            Returns((string virtualPath) => virtualPath);
        user.Setup(usr => usr.Identity).Returns(identity.Object);
        identity.SetupGet(ident => ident.IsAuthenticated).Returns(true);

        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Request).Returns(request.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Response).Returns(response.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Session).Returns(session.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.Server).Returns(server.Object);
        context.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(user.Object);

        return context.Object;
```

### }

```
        registrationView = new Mock<IRegistrationView>();
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.Address).Returns("Calle test");
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.EmailAddress).Returns("test@test.com");
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.Password).Returns("testpass");
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.FirstName).Returns("Name");
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.LastName).Returns("Surname");
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.DaytimePhoneNumber).Returns("666666666");
        registrationView.SetupGet(v => v.WholeSalers).Returns(new List<UserWholesaler>() { 
            new UserWholesaler(true) { CollaborationCode = "1234", Region = "TestReg", WholesalerCode = "10", WholesalerName = "TestWS", RegionName = "RegTest" } });
```

I wonder: is there any library that, with simply a call like "registrationView = new MockWithFilledProperties();", would allow me to create a Mock with properties filled with default values? If so, which one?

Thank you and kind regards.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Moq allows you to stub all properties with

```
registrationView.SetupAllProperties();
```

That will make all properties track their values (i.e. you can write some value to property and retrieve it later) and set all properties to their default values.

NOTE: You can use chained mock creation (aka specification queries) to setup mock more quickly

```
IRegistrationView view = Mock.Of<IRegistrationView>(ctx =>
    ctx.Address == "Calle test" &&
    ctx.EmailAddress == "test@test.com" &&
    ctx.Password == "testpass" &&
    ctx.FirstName == "Name" &&
    ctx.LastName == "Surname");
```

Comment: For http context, there are a bunch of fields that are read only. Can mock inject something into those?

Comment: Is there any way to setup properties with non default values? for instance Address with a random string

Answer (score 0):

Now u can just do:

```
Mock.Of<IMyclass>()
```

This will get you a default object to pass, if you don't really need the object and default answers from it's functions are ok this will do the trick.